# Reading next record in data reader

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I am doing a project to generate a word document using vb.net. Records are read from the sql server and word document is generated. Multiple records are read. While displaying records are displayed in table manner. Record dr(0) gets read but further records can't be read.

```
   Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
    oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, 5, ListBox1.Items.Count)
    oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6

    For c = 1 To ListBox1.Items.Count

        r = 1

        While dr.Read()


            oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = dr(i1).ToString

            r = r + 1
            If r > 5 Then


                Exit While

            End If

        End While
        i1 = i1 + 1
    Next
```

Comment: why not????  is there an error?  You sure you have a next record?

Comment: Could you explain the relationship between your ListBox.Items.Count and the number of column on your word table?.

Comment: Hope you are resetting your `i1` variable somewhere.  Seems potentially very buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks very strange. Note that dr.Read() changes to the next database row. Without understanding your code (strange relationship and not very descriptive variable names), I would suggest you read each rows then read each columns.

Here's an example.

```
    While dr.Read()
        For c As Integer = 0 To 3
           oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = dr(c).ToString
        Next

        r = r + 1
        If r > 5 Then
            Exit While
        End If

    End While
```

Comment: I solved it. For r = 1 To 5
            i1 = 0
            While dr.Read()
                For c = 1 To ListBox1.Items.Count
                    oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = dr(i1).ToString
                    i1 = i1 + 1
                    If i1 > ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
                        Exit While
                    End If
                Next
            End While
        Next